# Unity with C# for 3D odontogram system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I will like start in 3d programming with Unity and C#, but I would like to know where to start. I want to make a 3D odontogram is possible with Unity and C#, or is it just for games? Thanks! 
Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the short answer is that you can do it greatly. Since it's a 2D/3D engine, it is used for simulations in general. 
Look on the official site, there is [a gallery of non-games projects created with Unity](https://unity3d.com/showcase/gallery/non-games) (also medical projects for simulation and training purposes).

The best way to start is always following the [official tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) (they are oriented at the gaming approach because the typical user want to create games, but it doesn't ruin the generalistic approach to the engine).

Obviously, you should not just learn Unity, but also use a modeling software for creating and importing the 3D models that you're going to use (teeth, mouth, ecc... in your case).

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrea, I really want to learn Unity! I hope I can! Regards!

Comment: Best of luck, @Emily! I hope you'll enjoy it! ;)